# Filtering by secondary attribute in PostGIS. Issues with NULL

Tags: postgis

I'm new to PostGIS. I'm trying to perform a dissolve operation on polygons depending on a particular attribute fields called priFunc and priForm.
My SQL query is

```
   SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS new_geom, priFunc, priForm
   FROM os_greenspace_layer
   GROUP BY priFunc, priForm
```

This works fine and my output looks like this

[image]

Next, I'd like to remove any features which have a priForm of "Manmade Surface" and omit them completely. So the code now is

```
   SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS new_geom, priFunc, priForm
   FROM os_greenspace_layer
   WHERE priForm <> 'Manmade Surface'   
   GROUP BY priFunc, priForm
```

This gives an output that looks like this

[image]

So that works, but it also removes all the features where priForm is NULL and I want to keep those. I've tried using COALESCE to assign a value to the NULL fields but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS new_geom, priFunc, priForm
FROM os_greenspace_merged_clipped 
WHERE priForm <> 'Manmade Surface' or priForm is null
GROUP BY priFunc, priForm
```

Comment: That's great. Thank you. Yes, that works. SQL really requires a different mindset which I'm still struggling to get my head around so apologies for asking obvious questions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `IS DISTINCT FROM` or `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` to compare for (in)equality considering the null being not equal to a value

```sql
 SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS new_geom, priFunc, priForm
   FROM os_greenspace_layer
   WHERE priForm IS DISTINCT FROM 'Manmade Surface'   
   GROUP BY priFunc, priForm
```